# Summing a 3d array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to write a function that sums the element of a 3 dimensional array. I'm not getting any errors, but the resulting number is much larger than it should be. Any ideas where I might've gone wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum1(int const arr[][3][3]);

int const table[3][3][3] = 
{
    {
    {10, 11, 12},
    {13, 14, 15},
    {16, 17, 18}
    },
    {
    {20, 21, 22},
    {23, 24, 25},
    {26, 27, 28}
    },
    {
    {30, 31, 32},
    {33, 34, 35},
    {36, 37, 38}
    }
};

int sum1(int const arr[][3][3])
{
    int total, i, j, k;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            for(k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
            {
                total += arr[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Sum is %d\n", total);
    return total;
}

void main()
{
    sum1(table);
}
```

Comment: `total` is not initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always, and I mean *always* initialize your variables before using them:

```
int sum1(int const arr[][3][3])
{
    int total = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
            {
                total += arr[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Sum is %d\n", total);
    return total;
}
```

Not initializing a value is like saying to the compiler "I really don't care what the starting value is" so it ends up producing garbage data when you add on to that value.

It's also a good idea to move the definition of the variable as close as possible to where it's used so that there's no ambiguity as to what type it is. Since you can declare a variable used in a loop inside the loop that's a good place to do it except in cases where you need to use it outside the loop.